# Debug Nativescript on Visual Studio Code not working

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am able to use the cmd to run my nativescript project ( tns run android).
I open the project in VSCode, and add the Configuration to debug it.
I hit debug and it look like the debug try to run or something. (Look at the green bar under debug. However, nothing seem to run. I look at the debug console, nothing is print out.
Please take a look at screenshot.

Spent couple days on this issue and couldnt resolve it at all.
[VSCode Debug Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G11Vm.png)

Comment: You are probably hitting this known issue with VSCode 1.2.0 https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3358 - if that's the case try downgrading to older VSCode version (e.g 1.19)

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick. You save me.

Comment: @NickIliev I'm having this same exact issue with a project I tried to migrate from the playground.  Attempt to launch in Android and nothing happens, but the tns run android command works fine.  Has a new issue occurred with VS code 1.30.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Nick Iliev,

The problem actually is from VSCode itself. Somehow the version 1.20 doesn't work for debug. I end up removed and reinstalled version 1.19.2.
Everything is working straight forward now.
Once again, thanks Nick Iliev.

Comment: Hi, if you have a moment, can you please let me know if you observed this issue on Windows or macOS, and whether this suggestion would fix it for 1.20? https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension/issues/158#issuecomment-365639864

Comment: I observed this on Win7, running VSCode 1.20.1 (commit f88bbf9137d24d36d968ea6b2911786bfe103002).

The strange thing is: it worked a few days ago, but stopped working suddenly...

Comment: Here is the 1.19.3 version, for those who look for it: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19

Comment: 1) I tried with the `--debug-brk` flag on 1.20.1, no change it seems.

Comment: 2) I also tried --debug, no change. @EddyVerbruggen

Comment: Thanks for those answers. For anyone wanting to try an experimental new build of the extension, please DM at eddyverbruggen at gmail dot com.

Comment: Scrap that comment - I've made some progress fixing this. See follow up in https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension/issues/158