# Debug Nativescript on Visual Studio Code 1.30.2 not working

Tags: nativescript

I'm seeing the same basic issue as [Debug Nativescript on Visual Studio Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712538/debug-nativescript-on-visual-studio-code-not-working) but I'm on VSCode 1.30.2.  From what I can tell, this has been fixed, so I'm re-asking this question since apparently I have a different issue.

[image]

As you can see, VS thinks it's debugging, but nothing happens.  The blue progress bar under the Launch on Android continually moves from left to right, but I don't see anything.  I would expect to see an emulator popping up, but I don't see anything.

I followed the advanced install instructions on the NativeScript website.  Only thing I did do was skip the Chrome install, since I already have it installed.

Running the app from the command prompt correctly shows the emulator, but I can't figure out how to be able to run and attach it from VSCode.  The app is a brand new Angular App generated using the `tns create <app>` command.

Comment: If you launch the Emulator manually and then hit debug, will that work?

Comment: @Manoj so I've run "tns run" from the cmd prompt and the app is open in the emulator.  Then in VSCode I try the Launch on Android and Attach on Android and I see nothing happen.

Comment: Do you try attach after quitting tns run when app is launched?

Comment: @Manoj by quit I'm assuming you mean to Ctrl-C the tns create command?  If so, no change.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @Manoj No change.  I have a breakpoint set on an on Tap function, I would have figured that would have been triggered.

Comment: So it is now May 2020. Is this issue resolved?

Comment: So it is now May 2020. Is this issue resolved? I am having the same problems.  I have ios and android emulators running a basic Nativescript test template, I have set breakpoints in my src js code (app.component) and have tried run android and attach android but the breakpoints are not triggered. How do I fix this? None of the suggestions from 2019 or earlier are working for me.  Is there a newer solution?